# Wordpress Site Stuck waiting for domain

Tags: wordpress, http, pageload

http://legererestorations.com/

This WP site I manage is stuck 'Waiting for http://legererestorations.com/'.  The WP Dashboard loads and works just fine its the front end that is not loading.  The site is hosted on google cloud platform and everything seems to be fine on that end, I have 5 other similar WP sites hosted at the same location that run just fine.  I have tried disabling all the plugins still the same result.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [http://legererestorations.com/wp-admin](http://legererestorations.com/wp-admin).

Comment: yes, wp-admin (the wp dashboard) works just fine.